# Multiple variables in path

Tags: powershell

I am planning on using the following script by looping through a text file to set variables for the location of the source PDF, and designate the path to create a new folder (with week number) to move the source PDF to.

```
$pdfSource = 'C:\path\in\text\file'
$newFolder = 'C:\path\to\newfolder\in\text\file'
Get-ChildItem $pdfSource '*.pdf' -Recurse | foreach {
    $x = $_.LastWriteTime.ToShortDateString()
    $new_folder_name = Get-Date $x -UFormat %V
    $des_path = "C:\path\to\newfolder\$new_folder_name"

    if (Test-Path $des_path) {
        Move-Item $_.FullName $des_path
    } else {
        New-Item -ItemType Directory -Path $des_path
        Move-Item $_.FullName $des_path
    }
}
```

I can't seem to figure out the syntax for the line below to include the `$newFolder` path variable along with the existing `$new_folder_name` I'm creating.

```
$des_path = "C:\path\to\newfolder\$new_folder_name"
```

Comment: Are you looking for the `Join-Path` cmdlet? e.g. `$des_path = Join-Path $newFolder $new_folder_name`

Answer (score 5):

Option-1:

```
$des_path = "${newFolder}\${new_folder_name}"
```

Option-2:

```
$des_path = "${0}\${1}" -f $newFolder, $new_folder_name
```

Option-3:

```
$des_path = $newFolder + $new_folder_name
```

Option-4:

```
$des_path = Join-Path -Path $newFolder -ChildPath $new_folder_name
```

Answer (score 2):

There's nothing wrong with your approach to *string expansion* (interpolation):

```
$new_folder_name = 'foo' # sample value
$des_path = "C:\path\to\newfolder\$new_folder_name" # use string expansion
```

yields string literal `C:\path\to\newfolder\foo`, as expected.

[Adam's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53770765/45375) shows you *alternatives* to constructing file paths, with `Join-Path` being the most robust and PowerShell-idiomatic, albeit slow.
Another option is to use `[IO.Path]::Combine()`:

```
[IO.Path]::Combine('C:\path\to\newfolder', $new_folder_name)
```

---

The way you calculate the value for `$new_folder_name` *should* be problematic if your current culture is not `en-US` (US-English), but due to a bug actually isn't<sup>[1]</sup>; either way, it should be simplified:

Instead of:

```
$x = $_.LastWriteTime.ToShortDateString()
$new_folder_name = Get-Date $x -uformat %V
```

use:

```
$new_folder_name = Get-Date $_.LastWriteTime -uformat %V
```

That is, pass `$_.LastWriteTime` *directly* to `Get-Date`, as a `[datetime]` instance - no detour via a *string representation* needed.

---

<sup>[1] `.ToShortDateString()` returns a *culture-sensitive* string representation, whereas PowerShell typically uses the *invariant* culture to ensure cross-culture consistency; therefore, if you pass a *string* to a parameter that accepts a `[datetime]` instance, it is the *invariant* culture's formats that should (only) be recognized, not the *current* culture's. While that is true for *functions* written in *PowerShell*, in *compiled cmdlets* (typically C#-based), the *current* culture is unexpectedly applied; while this is a *bug*, a decision was made not to fix it for the sake of backward compatibility - see [this GitHub issue](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/3348)</sup>